# SQL Query with OR-Clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have two tables which I'm trying to combine and get data from one of them, depending on the query.

My sql query: (Which does not work)

```
SELECT *
FROM contacts
    INNER JOIN users
    (ON contacts.user_id_sender = users.id
    WHERE contacts.user_id_sender = '$user_id' AND contacts.status = 1)
        OR
    (ON contacts.user_id_receiver = users.id
    WHERE contacts.user_id_receiver = '$user_id' AND contacts.status = 1)
```

Basically, I have a class that needs to return the 'users' of which 'contacts' that is a part of the users id, and has a status of 1.

The idea behind this is a Contact/Friend system table. I basically have a Users and Contacts table, and I need to return the Users data depending on which of the contacts has relation to OUR user id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The () brackets in the `ON` where placed incorrect + there was a `WHERE` statement in the `ON` clause, which is not allowed.
This looks like what you wrote, but then syntactically works:

```
SELECT *
FROM contacts
INNER JOIN users
ON (contacts.user_id_sender = users.id 
     AND contacts.user_id_sender = '$user_id' 
     AND contacts.status = 1)
    OR
(contacts.user_id_receiver = users.id
AND contacts.user_id_receiver = '$user_id' AND contacts.status = 1)
```